# Sequelize with SQL Server returns error aggregate function or GROUP BY clause even I didn't used GROUP BY

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm built a app's backend with **ExpressJs** with **Sequelize** and **SQL Server**.
I've two tables, called User and Order. A user *hasMany* order.
I wanna list all **user** include their **order**(as count).

Here is my code:

```
User.findAll({
    attributes: ['id'],
    include: [
        {
            model: ProductBuy,
            attributes: [
                [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('Order.member_id')), 'total_active']
            ],
            where: {status: ['Active', 'Expired']}
        }
    ],
})
```

but it give me an error

> Column 'User.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't understand this, because I haven't used a group by yet.
But if I add a grouping like

```
group:['Order.member_id', 'User.id', 'Order.id']
```

It successfully gets the data, but the order isn't counted, it showed each order one by one in each user like this:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "orders": [
        {
            "total_active": 1
        },
        {
            "total_active": 1
        }
    ]
},
```

What I want is to say User A has 4 total_active, user B has 6 total_active like that

How do I achieve this?

> Table Structure
>
> ### User

```
|  id  |  name  |
|  1   | Andrew |
|  2   | Bruce  |
```

### Order

```
|  id  |  user_id  |   status   |
|  1   |     1     |   Active   |
|  2   |     1     |   Expired  |
|  3   |     2     |   Active   |
```

### Expected result

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Orders": [
                {
                    "total_active": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Orders": [
                {
                    "total_active": 1
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

> Screenshot result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you use COUNT with another fields you have to use GROUP BY

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*)
FROM [Order]
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Ok, I've used the Group by but it the result doesn't counted. You can check the result above.

Comment: try to remove 'order.id' from GROUP BY and of course from the SELECT

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I didn't add `order.id` in SELECT

Comment: can you give the table structure, i will try to write the query

Answer (score 0):

I think you can takeout the attribute field from `ProductBuy` and use it like this :

```
User.findAll({
    attributes: [
        'id'
        [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('Order.member_id')), 'total_active'] // <--- HERE
    ],
    include: [
        {
            model: ProductBuy,
            where: {status: ['Active', 'Expired']}
        }
    ],
    group:['User.id', 'Order.id']
})
```

> **NOTE :**
>
> If its counting duplicate records you can also use `DISTINCT` like
>   this
>
> `[Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.fn('DISTINCT',Sequelize.col('Order.member_id'))), 'total_active']`

Comment: Yes it duplicate, I mean it return each order one by one. And I did used distinct but it didn't distinct anything

Comment: Done, I've added the screenshoot. check it out. Thanks

Comment: @Blackjack, something is off, please check my code and your result doesn;t look like its generate from mine

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. I got `Column 'Order.product_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` Btw the database structure above is just column that has relation to each other. `product_id` is another column from table `order`